# If we rename the SQL server machine name, will this new name get reflected inside the SharePoint On-premsies "Manage content database settings" screen

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem, administration, content-database

Inside our SharePoint on-premises 2013 "Manage content database settings" screen, we got this info:-

[image]

where it mentioned that the database server name is SPSQL, but our system admin is saying that this server was turned off last week. but the SharePoint is still running.. so what could be causing this confusion?  could this SPSQL server get renamed and the new name was not reflected inside the above screen? because seems the actual database server name is different than what the SharePoint is listing..

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In order to use a different name from a pre-established SQL Server, you'd need to set the name via SQL Aliases on each of the SharePoint Servers via `cliconfg.exe`. It could be that this was already done, or there is a DNS alias set up in your DNS zone.